# Simple closure function

Tags: f#

I have following code

```
let f2 x:int = 
    fun s:string ->
        match x with
        | x when x > 0 -> printfn "%s" s
        | _ -> printfn "%s" "Please give me a number that is greater than 0"
```

And the compiler complain:

```
Unexpected symbol ':' in lambda expression. Expected '->' or other token.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two instances of the same problem.  When defining a function, putting `:*type*` at the end of the signature indicates that the function returns that type.  In this case you're indicating that you have a function `f2` which takes a parameter and returns an `int`. To fix it you need to put parenthesis around the annotation.  That syntax doesn't work in a lambda, so you simply get a compile error instead.

Answer (score 5):

You have to put parentheses around your type annotations:

```
let f2 (x : int) = 
    fun (s : string) ->
        match x with
        | x when x > 0 -> printfn "%s" s
        | _ -> printfn "%s" "Please give me a number that is greater than 0"
```

Also be aware if you omit the parentheses around `x` like in your example, this would mean the function `f2` returns an int, not constrain the type of `x` to be int.

---

Update for the comment:

> Why if I omit the parentheses around x, this would mean the function f2 returns an int?

Because that is how you specify the return type of functions.

What would be this in C#:

```
ReturnTypeOfFunction functionName(TypeOfParam1 firstParam, TypeOfParam2 secondParam) { ... }
```

would look like this in F#:

```
let functionName (firstParam : TypeOfParam1) (secondParam : TypeOfParam2) : ReturnTypeOfFunction =
    // Function implementation that returns object of type ReturnTypeOfFunction
```

A more detailed explanation can be found [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229.aspx).

Comment: Why if I omit the parentheses around x, this would mean the function f2 returns an int?

Answer (score 4):

Or let the compiler infer the types.  Try this:

```
let f2 x = 
    fun s ->
        match x with
        | x when x > 0 -> printfn "%s" s
        | _ -> printfn "%s" "Please give me a number that is greater than 0"
```